# Extracting specific values from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, extract

I have a symmetric matrix of form

```
 A  B  C  D  E
```

A 0  0  0  0  3

B 0  0  0  9  0

C 0  0  0  0  3

D 0  9  0  0  0

E 3  0  3  0  0

I need get some specific pair values from this (eg. BC, CD, E,D). Does
someone know a function of "R" associated with a data frame that point out the names of row*colums? I need an "automatized" method because I'm trying with big
matrices.
Thank you
Gastón

Comment: So do you have a data.frame or a matrix? You've used both terms and they are different objects in R. Better to give a `dput()` rather than have us guess what it is from the text representation.

Answer (score 0):

If you put data in dataframe, you can easily access all elements:

```
> ddf
  A B C D E
A 0 0 0 0 3
B 0 0 0 9 0
C 0 0 0 0 3
D 0 9 0 0 0
E 3 0 3 0 0
> 
> 
> ddf[1,1]
[1] 0
> ddf["A","B"]
[1] 0
> 
> ddf["E","B"]
[1] 0
> ddf["E","A"]
[1] 3
>
```